# How to query by time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.5

| device_id | device_created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 10e7983e-6a7b-443f-b0fe-d5e6485a502c | 2022-08-10 20:55:16.695 |

i have a table where my date/time is of form: 2022-08-10 20:55:16.695 This is a timestampped object. I tried the following query but didn't return any rows:

`select * from device where to_char(device_created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FFF') = '2022-08-10 20:55:16.695'`

The type of device_created_at is "timestamp without time zone"

How do i query based on timestamp in postgressql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try comparing timestamp values in place of strings:

```
SELECT * 
FROM device 
WHERE device_created_at = CAST('2022-08-10 20:55:16.695' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oNhPVUwKGR8B56b1ZSmQQh/1).